# how to redirect to the previous previous page in php

Tags: php, html

How to redirect to the previous previous page in PHP that mean it will go back 2 time

I use this code

```
<?php header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); ?>
```

And its work fine it took me to the previous page But I want it to take me one more time back how can I do that? Is there any function can do that?

I hope someone can help me coz I really need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on how much reliability you need. In general i use the javascript " history.back();". But if you want a more reliable option for sensitive areas of your project i would define an array for saving the page names for then calling then back with "header".

Comment: can u tell me how to save the header + use it later in other page

Comment: justa save the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); passively on every page(within an array), so you can go back all the steps you want by just going back in the array.

Answer (score 3):

Don't rely on `HTTP_REFERER`, it may not be set.

If you want to redirect to a page after some processing pass along the URL you want to redirect to. So you get something like:

```
header("Location: " . $_POST["redirect_url"]);
```

Comment: the problem is that i have category . Car , Bike , plan . and for eash category it has category id , the user will be in car category after that will choose a car BMW then go to car_option.php then after done the option he will press add to the trolley now i don't want it to take him to the trolley.php , i want it to take him back to the car category